# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index when there is no actual duplicate

Tags: sql-server, indexing, ssis, ssms, etl

I'm getting a "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object" error when trying to insert a record which does not exist in the table through a SSIS ETL job. This error, however, does not appear when I put a 'where' clause to specify the exact record the job is complaining about.

Ex., I'll get the error for primary key (100, 200, 300). I've confirmed that this combination does not exist in the source table, so I know the error doesn't exist at that level. But when I put a where clause that filters the source table to have records with just '100' for the first primary key field value, the job runs without errors. Could this be a buffer issue or something with the environment?

Comment: No, it will not be a buffer or environment issue. What is the data type of the first key, If it is integer then '100','0100' will be the same.

Comment: You might be trying to insert 2 or more records with the same key on your insert. The error message is the same, even if neither of them were already inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary key data type is int and in the table '0100' will already exist and which is same as 100 , please verify using wild card whether record like (00100,0100,000100) exist already or not if not then it is a different issue.